# Comparing 2 randomly generated lists in python

Tags: python

I am trying to make a program that will generate a list filled with randomly generated characters, then repeatedly randomizing another until both of them match up.

However, when I run the following program, even at the lowest value, it will continuously run, forever.

```
import random
import string

combo_length = int(input("pick the number of characters(please write in numbers ONLY): "))
combo_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
combo = []
for x in range(combo_length):
     combo.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
print(''.join(combo))

combo2 = []
for x in range(combo_length):
     combo2.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
print(''.join(combo2))

count = 0
while combo != combo2:
     count=count+1
     for x in range(combo_length):
          combo2.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
     print("testing")
     print(''.join(combo2))
print("the word was", combo)
print("it took", count, "attempts")
```

Comment: You should initialize combo2 with an empty list at the beginning of the while loop.

Comment: BTW: If you want to brute-force random combinations, it makes sense to try systematically instead of randomly, because that way, you're trying each combination only exactly once.

Comment: @Dschoni how would i go about doing that?

Comment: It says I have to wait 3 minutes to accept an answer

Comment: Instead of randomly choosing from combo_characters, for each position you would loop trough the list. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.product

Comment: thank you! Ill make sure to check this out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You keep on appending to your second list in your while loop.
Simple reset your list during each iteration:

```
import random
import string
combo_length = 3
combo_characters = string.ascii_letters + string.digits + string.punctuation
combo = []
for x in range(combo_length):
     combo.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
print(''.join(combo))

combo2 = []
for x in range(combo_length):
     combo2.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
print(''.join(combo2))

count = 0
while combo != combo2:
     count=count+1
     combo2 = [] # <-- reset list
     for x in range(combo_length):
          combo2.append(random.choice(combo_characters))
print("the word was", ''.join(combo2))
print("it took", count, "attempts")
```